# Div tag doesn't work as block tag

Tags: html, css, block

In my code, there are two DIVs in the aside:

```
<aside>
<div id="as_profile"></div>
<div id="as_search"></div>
</aside>
```

As you know, DIV tag is block level tag.

So, contents in each DIVs must not show in same line. They must use other line, but contents in two DIVs show in a line:

[image: Problem]

(blue zone is `#as_profile area`, greeen zone is `#as_search area`.)

You see a line that shows both `#as_profile` content and `#as_search` content.

They must work like this:

[image: Desired solution]

So I add:

```
#as_profile { display : block ; }
#as_search { display : block ; }
```

but even with this code, the problem isn't fixed.

Why DIV tags work like inline tag? and How can I fix them?

[Here is a Jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PC7R4/)

Comment: If you want to see code : http://goo.gl/t4tUiN

Comment: JSFiddle or bust bro.

Comment: You should post the code here or jsfiddle, linking to an image doesn't help us solve your problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with the code you provided... some other code in your project may be causing the issue: see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/f96zq/1/)

Comment: if I had to guess, I'd say some other css is overriding the display:block. for all we know you have something like `#container aside div{display:inline-block}` declared somewhere else. id should be given enough weight to override but you could probably write some specific selectors that would override a single level id declaration. You'd need a fiddle for us to inspect

Comment: here is JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PC7R4/

Just aside part has error

Comment: @AlienWebguy Sorry here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/PC7R4/

Comment: @MitchGlenn Sorry here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/PC7R4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this style to stop the search DIV from floating:

```
#as_search { clear: both; }
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/PC7R4/1/)

*The search DIV is floating because of the floated li elements in the ul list in the DIV that precedes it so you need to clear the float behavior*